# Define $\phi:G/H \rightarrow G/K$ by $\phi(Ha)=Ka$. Prove: $\phi$ is a well defined function.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, abstract-algebra

> Let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$, with $H \subseteq K$. Define $\phi:G/H \rightarrow G/K$ by $\phi(Ha)=Ka$.
>
> Prove: $\phi$ is a well defined function. [That is, if $Ha=Hb$, then $\phi(Ha)=\phi(Hb)$.]

***Question:*** To show a function is well defined, do we show that if $x=y$ then $f(x)=f(y)$?  Isn't this the same as an injective function?

Since $\phi(Ha)=Ka$, if $Ha=Hb$, then $Ka=Kb$.  Is this what well defined is? I am not sure what this says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have what you need to show right, but that's not the same as an injective function.

With an injective function, the implication runs if $f(x)=f(y)$ then it must be that $x=y$.

What we're trying to show here is that if $x$ and $y$ are, in fact, the same thing, then $f(x)$ and f(y) produce the same result regardless of whether we choose to call it $x$ or $y$. Basically, your question asks you to deal with the following worry:

The (possible) function $\phi$ is supposed to map cosets of $H$ it cosets of $K$. However, we can refer to the same coset many different ways: $Ha$ could just as well be written $Hg$ for any other $g\in Ha$. It's not at all obvious, then, that our rule of "map $Ha$ to $Ka$" gives clear instructions. It could be that two perfectly equal ways of writing one coset, $Hg_1=Hg_2$ wind up producing distinct cosets of $K$, $Kg_1\neq Kg_2$. (well, no it couldn't, but that's what you're supposed to prove.)

Edit: Rather than just describe the worry, it might be easier to show it. $D_4$ has a few normal subgroups; two of them are $A=\{e,r,r^2,r^3\}$ and $B=\{e,s,r^2,sr^2\}$. Let's try to define the homomorphism $\phi$ described in your problem from $D_4/A$ to $D_4/B$. The elements of $D_4/A$ are the cosets $sA$ and $A$. The latter is exactly the same coset as $rA$. Our description of $\phi$ tells us that $\phi(rA)=rB$ or, likewise, $\phi(A)=B$. But the cosets $rB$ and $B$ are not the same, so now we have $rB=\phi(rA)=\phi(A)=B$, but $rB\neq B$, so $\phi$ provides contradictory values for the same input.

Comment: So, by showing that if $Ha=Hb$ then $Ka=Kb$, means the function $\phi$ gives clear instructions?

Comment: Right, it's proving that, if we put the same thing into the function (regardless of the details of how we name that input) we get the same thing out. I've updated my answer to give an example of a group for which $\phi$ fails to be well-defined, if it helps make the problem we're trying to avoid clearer.